# Can document text change with captions?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I'm using MS Word 2013.

If I'm using captions, is there a way to change the text **within** the document as I add new Figures and those numbers change?

Answer (score 1):

> Can document text change with captions?

Yes, it can.

You can insert cross-references to captions into the text. Then, when a caption changes, your cross-references get updated.

[image: Word cross-reference caption]

After changing your caption, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select the entire document and then <kbd>F9</kbd> to update the cross-references.